# Replacing this() with a new value in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm iterating through every element of a class, and I'm replacing all ** with **bold** tags.

However, it isn't outputting as I want. I used window alerts, and checked, and the regex is converting it correctly, however the `$(this).html = txt` doesn't seem to be working. I've tried using `innerHTML`, val. Nothing seems to work.

The code commented out does work, however I can't refer to all of the Id's because it's possible for new ones to be added, hence me iterating through each element of the class.

```js
    $(document).ready(function () {
    setTimeout(function(){
        var bold = /\*\*(\S(.*?\S)?)\*\*/gm;
        $(".grid-text").each(function() {
            var currentElement = $(this).html();
            var txt = currentElement.replace(bold, '<strong>$1</strong>');
            $(this).html= txt;
        });
        // var s = document.getElementById("001_1_1").innerHTML;
        // var txt = s.replace(bold, '<strong>$1</strong>');
        // document.getElementById("001_1_1").innerHTML = txt;
    }, 3000);
});
```

Comment: what element is `.grid-text`? try to assign as text not html

Comment: `$(this).html= txt;` this means assigning txt to the `html` property, which is a jQuery decorated function, not the 'html'  of the element

Comment: What does this have to do with [tag:java]? *"`$(this).html = txt` doesn't seem to be working"* It seems you haven't read [the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/html/#html2). It's pretty clear from the documentation how it is to be used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.html` is a function:

```
$(this).html(txt);
```

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette better luck next time :)

Comment: `.html` is still a property. However, it resolves to a function that needs to be called, you should not assign to it.

Comment: @FelixKling can you please give a link for detail.

Comment: Detail about what? What a property is?

Comment: @FelixKling where i can see details of `.html` is a property.

Comment: `$(...)` returns a jQuery *object*. Objects have a properties. The *value* of a property can be any JavaScript value. Example: `var foo = { bar: 42, baz: function() {}}`. The object `foo` has two properties: `bar` and `baz`. The value of `foo.bar` is a number. The value of `foo.baz` is a function. You can learn more about objects on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects) or [YDKJS](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/this%20%26%20object%20prototypes/ch3.md).

Comment: @FelixKling thanks i know this already i thought `.html` is a built in `property`

Comment: No, it's a property of a jQuery object. I said that it is a property because you are saying in your answer that it is not, which is incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

Try passing txt as a parameter to the `.html()` function:

```
$(this).html(txt);
```